# Adding new input using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down called roomfac1 on my form and I would like *roomfac2*, *roomfac3*... (duplicate dropdowns) to be added when the user clicks on the **Add** button. How do I accomplish this using jQuery? In addition to this, I would also like the user to dynamically remove the newly created inputs as well.

I've uploaded my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ecRXP/2/

```
<select name="roomFac1" id="roomFac1">
  <option selected="selected">Any</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Add" class="pmbtn" id="addFac"/>
<input type="button" value="Remove" class="pmbtn" id="removeFac"/>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any JavaScript; that's probably why it doesn't work =p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addFac').click(function(){
        var $objs = $('select[name*=roomFac]');
        var n = $objs.size() + 1;
        var $obj = $objs.first().clone();
        $obj.attr('name', 'roomFac'+n).attr('id', 'roomFac'+n);
        $obj.appendTo($('body'));
    });
    $('#removeFac').click(function(){
        var $objs = $('select[name*=roomFac]');
        if($objs.size() > 1){
           $objs.last().remove();
        }
    });
});
```

and here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kfm5b/2/

Comment: How would you go about removing the most recently added input?

Comment: It works great but one last question I have to ask is how would I prevent the first roomFac (i.e. roomFac1) from being deleted?

Comment: Haha I'm worried about the user removing all of the drop downs when there should be at least one left :-)

Comment: It works but removes all of the dropdowns instead of one, but it doesn't remove the last one

Comment: you must have done something wrong, check out the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/smefh/).

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="add">
        <a href="#" id="add">Add</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <select name="roomFac1" id="roomFac1">
            <option selected="selected">Any</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var $form = $("form"),
    $firstRow = $(".row:first"),
    totalRows;

$("form").on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).closest("div").remove();
});

$("#add").on("click", function (e) {
    var $clonedRow = $firstRow.clone(),
        totalRows = "1",
        newNum;

    e.preventDefault();

    totalRows = $(".row").length;
    newNum = parseInt(totalRows, 10) + 1;

    $clonedRow.find("select").attr("name", "roomFac" + newNum);
    $clonedRow.find("select").attr("id", "roomFac" + newNum);
    $clonedRow.append('<a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>');
    $form.append($clonedRow);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `.clone`, like this:

```
var roomFacCount = 1;

$('#addFac').on('click', function() {
    var $lastRoomFac = $('#roomFac' + roomFacCount);
    roomFacCount++;
    $lastRoomFac.after($lastRoomFac.clone(true, true).attr('id', 'roomFac' + roomFacCount));
});

$('#removeFac').on('click', function() {
    if (roomFacCount > 1) {
        var $lastRoomFac = $('#roomFac' + roomFacCount);
        roomFacCount--;
        $lastRoomFac.remove();
    }
});
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/HGCSC/)